# How to stop Body Scroll On Touch Devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll

I know many of you have already asked this question but did not find any suitable solution that is why I am asking this one again!!!

I have creating a website in word-press and I am using push-menu in this website. The requirement is that when the menu is open the rest part of body does not scroll, only menu scroll should be worked, Now I am using overflow hidden which is working well on desktop but cant worked on IPAD and IPHONE and also apply position fixed but after scrolling half of page if someone click on menu bar due to position fixed complete site scroll to top of website which is not a good user experience, So please tell me how to achieve this scenario on touch devices.

Below is my site URL

http://tvcstage.wpengine.com/

Thanks
Mayank

Comment: Don't use fixed positioning in small touch devices, it's dangerous (open keyboard and so on), and you can workaround the same with absolute positioning.

Comment: @marcos can you please explain this is brief how I can achieve this using position absolute, means some kind of example

Comment: Absolute positioning it's the same as fixed, but absolute attachs to the closest relative parent element (in last instance `<body>` tag), and the fixed positioning attachs to viewport ( or `<html>` tag).

Comment: @marcos thanks for quick reply, but still I am not getting where to give position absolute. Do you mean that when I open menus than body should goes position absolute or please elaborate it.

Comment: I can't visit your website with a mobile device since I'm in work, but if you provide us a working example following the rules of [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) maybe I can help you soon.